# How to drilldown a stacked column highchart to show all stacks instead of clicked

Tags: highcharts, drilldown, stackedbarseries

I am trying to get my stacked column highchart display all stacks on drilldown . In my example below, when i click on a stack it only drills down to that stack level. I have tried this myself but i have been unable to get it to work. My expected output is that i click on a month and i see the stacked columns for each day

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: Here is my current version: http://jsfiddle.net/aNmBV/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is mainly in the way you organize your data. I have seen similar setups like this quite often and it's not a flexible way. So instead of:

```
data = [{
    y: 6863,
    color: colors[2],
    drilldown: {
        name: ['IPad Jan'],
        categories: ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31'],
        level: 1,
        data: [10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81, 10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81, 10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81, 10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81, 10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81, 10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81, 10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81, 10.85, 7.35, 33.07],
        color: colors[2]
    }}]
```

Do:

```
data = [{
    y: 6863,
    color: colors[2],
    drilldown: 'january'
]
```

Then you have an data structure like this on the side

```
var drilldownData = {
    'january': [/*data structured correctly for drilldown of january*/],
    'february': [...]
}
```

So in your "click" event you do:
   setChart(drilldown.name, drilldown.categories, **[drilldownData[this.drilldown]]**, drilldown.color, drilldown.level, drilldown.type);